# Python 3, Math.floor on "long" numbers

Tags: python-3.x, math

> > > int(-9/8)
> > >       -1
> > >       math.floor(-9/8)
> > >       -2

Works as expected, but:

> > > int(-27185501994412122128269814042/ 1893973573)
> > >       -14353686018623303680
> > >       math.floor(-27185501994412122128269814042/ 1893973573)
> > >       ***-14353686018623303680*** notice the minus, should be -1435368601862330368**1**

any idea why? and how to solve?

> > > int(-27185501994412122128269814042 % 1893973573)
> > >       1012149580 > 0

Comment: That's why you use the `//` floor-division operator instead of division and then floor. `/` is a floating-point operation, and you're losing precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is wrong in both cases as the correct fraction is `-14353686018623303214` as

```
-27185501994412122128269814042 - (-14353686018623303214*1893973573)
= 1012149580 
< 1893973573
```

The other result is obtained as the quotient is first transformed into floating point format and then back into integer.

Comment: Solved by using:
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 30
int(math.floor(Decimal(op2) / Decimal(op1)))